# Chart HTML with Zoom scriptable events

Tags: javascript, html, database, charts

I am looking for a chart (free if possible) for a html aplication that can do zoom in and out but with a especial event, zoom events. I need this because I can't load all the points in a chart with 32000000 records in a DB, but I can create something like a preview and if the user wants it, do zoom on it and load all the points in that range.

I have a Table with records second to second about a machine and in 3 days I got about 32M of records so, it is impossible to the user read it all, and it is completely useless see a very hard chart. Sometimes a user can need to see a moment with a lot of exactitude so, that is the idea, do zoom and load it (Json, Ajax, whatever).

Any idea?

PD: Please, NO Flash

Answer (score 0):

Flot may be what you want: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

It supports selection events which could allow you to make zoom functionality: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html

Comment: But, this chart load all the points. I need a chart that load the points when i make the "zoom in"